# Relational queries on Parse and Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, relation

I am trying to get the objects that are relational to a class.

Bellow is my query:

```
var user = PFUser.currentUser()
println("PERSON\(user)")
var relation = user!.relationForKey("followingThings")
var queryTeste = relation.query()
queryTeste?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    println("OBJECTS FROM RELATIONAL QUERY\(object)")
})
```

If you look at the output I am able to retrieve my relational objects, BUT... I get an error just before retrieving them.

I've tried different combinations in order to get rid of it but no success. Also most of the questions here are on objective C and sintaxe and methods differ a bit.

Any ideas about what could be causing the error?

> PERSONOptional( {
>       email = "myemail@gmail.com";
>       emailVerified = 1;
>       followingThings = " Things>";
>       points = 10;
>       username = Me; })
>
> 2015-08-31 19:16:32.161 App[30479:9376080] [Error]: field
>   followingThings cannot be included because it is not a pointer to
>   another object (Code: 102, Version: 1.8.0)
>
> OBJECTS FROM RELATIONAL QUERYOptional([
>
> Things: 0x7ff031a736c0, objectId: G29f9Wfqj5, localId: (null)> {
>       description = Camping;
>       searchKey = camping;
>       usersFollowing = " _User>"; },
>
> Things: 0x7ff031a76520, objectId: IPEg4G2Qec, localId: (null)> {
>       description = "Animal Care";
>       searchKey = "animal care";
>       usersFollowing = " _User>"; },
>
> Things: 0x7ff031a76120, objectId: Jg4oRjebKE, localId: (null)> {
>       description = Bicycling;
>       searchKey = bycicling;
>       usersFollowing = " _User>"; },
>
> Things: 0x7ff031a75810, objectId: TseQvlo6AL, localId: (null)> {
>       description = Boating;
>       searchKey = boating;
>       usersFollowing = " _User>"; }])

Answer (score 1):

works for me like that

```
    var relation = currentUser.relationForKey("product")
                        relation.query()?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({

                            (let productResult, let error) -> Void in
                            //println("result:\(productResult!.count)")

                            if let result = productResult {
                                //println(result.count)
                                for product in result {
println(product)
}
}
}
```